# Scrollspeed on a bicubic bezier curve

Tags: javascript, math, scrollmagic

This website: https://gladeye.com/ has a very interesting scrolling behavior. You move between slides (screens) and it feels like snappy scrolling where you move from slide to slide. But in fact, the website scrolls continuously, but moves the slides with CSS 3D-transforms slower and faster based on a bicubic Bezier curve (i looked at their minified code).

[image]

Since I am not an expert in math and Bezier curves, I am having a hard time implementing this. I wonder if someone can help me and give me a heads up with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some approximation curve. Let's build a pair of curves for every page (screen).

Given values: `ScreenSize`, `MaxSpeed` at moments `h = 0` and `h = ScreenSize`, `MinSpeed` at moment `h = ScreenSize/2`

We build two (mirror) Bezier curves.
Control points:

```
first curve
P[0]  = (0, MaxSpeed)
P[1]  = (A, MaxSpeed)
P[2]  = (ScreenSize/2 - 3 * A, MinSpeed)
P[3]  = (ScreenSize/2, MinSpeed)
second curve
P[0]  = (ScreenSize/2, MinSpeed)
P[1]  = (ScreenSize/2 + 3 * A, MinSpeed)
P[2]  = (ScreenSize - A, MaxSpeed)
P[3]  = (ScreenSize, MaxSpeed)
```

Play with parameter A (it is rough ScreenSize/10) and with coefficient `3` to achieve desired form.

Curves for next screens are shifted by `ScreenSize`, `2*ScreenSize` and so on.